# hibernate insert into select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

How can I generate insert statements like `insert into table (sequence.nextval, 'b0)` using hibernate?

Hibernate currently selects the `sequence.nextval` value and only then it uses the value to insert the entry in the table.

Note: I'm not very fond of custom id generators.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate selects `sequence.nextval` because it has to return that value back to you (e.g. set ID on your entity). Unless you're doing something very esoteric I strongly doubt this has a big impact on performance (e.g. it's nothing compared to the actual insert). That said, you can look at Hibernate's sequence hi-lo generator - it would only access the sequence once in a while instead of every insert.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle 10 client or above, check out sequence-identity in the most recent Hibernate versions to do what you're asking for.